# Stop a formula field from removing the special characters

Tags: custom-object, formula, formula-field

This is a generic question. I want to know if its possible to stop a formula field of a custom object from removing the special characters like quotation marks.

Comment: what you are tying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure what you want to achieve but if you want to keep the `"` on your output value you could do something like `' " Sample text " '` OR `' " ' & SampleText & ' " '`.  This would be displayed as `" SampleText "`